# How to embed the wordpress posts section in a custom template that I designed myself

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I can't insert WordPress posts in my personal template that I designed and activate it automatically

I have designed a wordpress template with html, css and javascript, and I have managed to install my template using PHP on my wordpress website, but now I want the posts I create in wordpress on the page. I want to see the main page of my website, what code should I use and in which folders and files to be able to see a news list like my WordPress posts on the main page?